# how to run fastapi to cpanel use passenger_wsgi.py file

Tags: python, fastapi, cpanel

I searched a lot on the internet to run Fastapi on Capnel, but unfortunately I did not find a suitable way. Please help me if someone is skilled in running Fastapi. I searched a lot and I keep getting 500 error.

Python 3.10.13 and install pip install "fastapi[all]"

this is code not worked

```
import imp
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'main.py')
application = wsgi.app
```

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

```
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))


def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    message = 'It works!\n'
    version = 'Python %s\n' % sys.version.split()[0]
    response = '\n'.join([message, version])
    return [response.encode()]
```